# Rewrite code from base to pipeline/tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyr

I would like to keep my code in the style of tidyr with pipelines.
Also because I like to the fact to be able to format the table neatly afterwards.
I have tried to google/stackoverflow my problem but was not able to find a solution.

here my code:

```
datafile %>%
  select(Var1, IQ) %>%
  with(.,addmargins(table(.))) %>%
  kbl(caption = "Var1 with IQ") %>%
  kable_classic()
```

However, as IQ has many individual items, this frequency table is very wide.
I would like to add cuts/breaks with categories to this code.

If I write this code in baseR style it works:

```
table(datafile$Var1,cut(datafile$IQ,breaks=c(70,85,100,115,130,145)))
```

But as soon as I try to include the "cut" and "break" arguments to my pipeline code it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please don't bold your code with `**` in the markdown. Instead format it as code by putting three backticks \`\`\` before the code starts, and three backticks after it ends. (Or highlight it and select the "code format" button that looks like curly braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `dplyr` we use `mutate` to add or modify columns of data. This is untested as you don't share any sample data, but I think it should work:

```
datafile %>%
  mutate(IQ_bins = cut(IQ, breaks=c(70,85,100,115,130,145))) %>%
  select(Var1, IQ_bins) %>%
  with(., addmargins(table(.))) %>%
  kbl(caption = "Var1 with IQ groups") %>%
  kable_classic()
```